# JavaFX: clone XYChart.Series doesn't dork

Tags: java, javafx, charts, clone, linechart

Hy guys, I have this problem:

```
XYChart.Series x = (XYChart.Series)((XYChart.Series)item).clone();
```

**Error**: `clone()` has protected access in `java.lang.Object`

How can I resolve it?
It's important that `x` is a *copy of value* and **NOT** a pointer to the cloned item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `clone` requires this method to be implemented by the type. A major part, if not all of the JavaFX classes don't do this since most contain properties that could have non-cloneable listeners attached.

This means you'll need to implement copying a `XYChart.Series` yourself.

Since you want a deep copy of the series, you could use the following code. Copying all teh `XYChart.Data` objects may or may not be necessary depending on your use case:

```
public static <S, T> XYChart.Series<S, T> copySeries(XYChart.Series<S, T> series) {
    XYChart.Series<S, T> copy = new XYChart.Series<>(series.getName(),
            series.getData().stream()
                  .map(data -> new XYChart.Data<S, T>(data.getXValue(), data.getYValue()))
                  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList)));
    return copy;
}
```

If copying the `Data` objects isn't neccessary, the code could be simplified to

```
public static <S, T> XYChart.Series<S, T> copySeries(XYChart.Series<S, T> series) {
    XYChart.Series<S, T> copy = new XYChart.Series<>(series.getName(),
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(series.getData()));
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! The first snippet is perfect